# Overriding paint of combobox using WndProc

Tags: vb.net, combobox, drawing, messaging

I've overriden the WndProc of the ComboBox and I am drawing my own combo box, a code snippet is below:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case &HF

            Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

            If ComboBoxRenderer.IsSupported Then
                Dim pTextBoxRect As New Rectangle(Me.ClientRectangle.X, Me.ClientRectangle.Y, Me.ClientRectangle.Width, Me.ClientRectangle.Height)
                ComboBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(g, pTextBoxRect, _tbState)
                 ' .... and so on
    End Select
End Sub
```

Though the old control is still being painted as my drawn combo box is just overlapping the old drawing.  Is there a way to stop it drawing the default combo box?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Why override the wndproc? why not just override the OnPaint method?

Comment: ...or use a regular ComboBox using the OwnerDraw capabilities?

Comment: Adrian - The OnPaint method for a combo box does not draw the combo box.
Fredrik - I am using a regular combo box and the OwnerDraw

This is a regular combobox and I'm overriding the WndProc method to display the combo box in Visual Styles as I can not set this at application level due to this being a plugin for an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using is the only way to get it done, but you are right, it draws over the top of the default combobox, and there is no way around this while still using the combobox control.

To truly get a custom drawn combobox, you need to go up one level higher in the object tree, but then you end up having to recreate almost all of the functionality of the combobox.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Stewbob I did have a hunch that was going to be the case.